# How does this case of the substitution rule of integration work?

Tags: integration, analysis, substitution

[Picture of the integration step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOjIq.png)

I found the integration step shown in the picture in a book on quantum mechanics and I really don't understand how it works.

It has to be some magic trick using substitution.

I would solve it using integration by parts, is there any problem with that?

Comment: You can use parts instead. But the idea is pretty straightforward: if you differentiate $e^{-2\lambda x}$ with respect to $\lambda$ you get a factor of $x$ on the outside, so if you do that twice then you get the $x^2$. Then you can pull the derivative outside to make things easier at the end. This is sometimes called "Feynman's trick" or just "differentiation under the integral sign". It's less obvious that it can be used when you have to make up the parameter, like if you were going to use it on $\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x} dx$ (which seemingly has no "$\lambda$").

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Ian

Comment: They're actually using [something different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "magic trick" is "differentiation"!

To find $\frac{\partial^2 e^{-2\lambda x}}{\partial\lambda^2}$, differentiate twice. I presume that you know that the derivative of $e^{a\lambda}$, with respect to $\lambda$, is $ae^{a\lambda}$.  Here, $a= -2x$ so the first derivative is $(-2x)e^{-2\lambda x}$.  Then the second derivative just does that again: $(-2x)(-2x)e^{-2\lambda x}= 4x^2e^{-2\lambda x}$.

$x^2e^{-2\lambda x}= \frac{1}{4}(4x^2e^{-2\lambda x})$ and they have simply replaced $4x^2e^{-2\lambda x}$ by $\frac{\partial^2 e^{-2\lambda x}}{\partial\lambda^2}$ which is equal to it.